# dropdown menu using a label

Tags: c#, winforms

Ok I have been redoing an app I created 4 years ago. I was wandering if there was a way to create a drop down menus using labels.

Currently I have a few buttons on a borderless form and the menustrip is just not looking right.

So I figured if I do a binding on a label I can achieve what I am looking for. I have a label that opens and hides my tab control.

Is there a way to extend that when on the mouse hover event it will produce a drop down menu?

Example

Customize (label)

> Commands (tab)
>   User Input (tab)
>   Web Commands (tab)

Is it possible to do a drop down menu to list each tab in my tab control individually? My main label Customize opens and hides the tab control.

I really don't want to use menuStrips or buttons or anything because it just does not look right. I have two buttons one is a log out button and the other will be an update commands button once I get the tab Control situated.

If it can't be done then I will just leave it the way it is, and just click the tab I want. The picture below is my main form. I click customize and it brings up a tabControl. I am wanting the form to be border-less. I dont want a white strip going across the top of the form. I am trying to make the form  smooth. So when i hover my mouse over customize it will display the tabs in the TabControl. Like a menu. See both pictures below.

[image]

Update :     This is what i am trying to do, using a Label only.  I do not want to use any of these:
toolStrips, 
toolStripContainers, 
menuStrips, 
ContextMenuStrip, 
buttons 
comboBoxes.

I want to use solely a label. And only a label.

[image]

Comment: See [How to: Create and Set a Custom Renderer for the ToolStrip Control in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dy4ys6z6(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: This is for a toolStrip not a label. Read my question. I do not want to use toolStrips, toolStripContainers, menuStrips, ContextMenuStrip, buttons or comboBoxes. I want to use solely a label. The toolStrip makes a borderless form look tacky.

Comment: Maybe you should read that link.  You can control the paint process of the items with a custom renderer, so you can make it "look" like a label, whatever that means.

Comment: @LarsTech look at my edit

Comment: Your post is confusing.  You are talking about labels, tabcontrols and a borderless form.  Are you talking about a borderless tabcontrol now?

Comment: @LarsTech I took the tabControl out because i was not yet to the point of implementing it. What you see is the UI. In my tabControl I will have four tabs Commands, Social Commands, Web Commands and User Info. What i am wanting to do is when i hoover my mouse over the Customize label, it will show a drop down menu of the tab name in the Tab Control. It would be the same as a Menu strip but This is the Lay out. If it wont work then i will just keep it the way i had it. I click on the label Customize, and the TabControl appears, then i will just select the tab.

Comment: My actual app was like that. But i am redoing it with all 8,000 lines of code. But i want to go for the futuristic look. Now keep in mind that this is using System.Speech as well. So the labels are more of looks than actually functionality. Everything will be primarily done by voice.

Comment: also what your seeing in the picture is a list box named lstCommands its the same way i press the commands label the listbox appears, then press it again and it hides. I am using if statements to accomplish this. I figured it would not be this hard.

Comment: @LarsTech How is this confusing? to me its pretty straight forward. Making a label into a drop down menu. Its either going to be a Yes It Will Work or No It Won't Work.

Comment: The hard part is figuring out what you are asking.  As far as I can tell, you want to use a ContextMenuStrip to show menu items when you click on a label.  The borderless tabcontrol seems like a different question.

Comment: @LarsTech What are you talking about a borderless TabControl, that was not even in the Question?

Comment: @LarsTech Forget the Picture!, You have one label. How do i make that label in to a drop down menu? I only want the label nothing else.

Comment: Your post: `brings up a tabControl. I am wanting it to be border-less. I dont want a white strip going across the top.`  What's not very clear is: `How do i make that label into a drop down menu?`  You use a ContextMenuStrip and show your menu items.  If they don't look right, use a custom renderer.

Comment: The form is borderless. All I want to know if I can use the label in mouse hover event to show the tabs in the tabcontrol

Comment: Besides renders can only be used in the things I don't want

Comment: In the MouseHover event of the label, show the ContextMenuStrip.

Comment: look at the edit on the update in the question

Comment: @LarsTech I don't know how much plainer i can explain this.

Comment: @LarsTech  I do not want to use any of these: toolStrips, toolStripContainers, menuStrips, ContextMenuStrip, buttons or comboBoxes. I only want to use a label. (LABEL ONLY)

Comment: The ContextMenuStrip is your friend here, so it's not clear why you are ruling that out.  In your scenario with "floating labels", what is the trigger to make them disappear again?  Things get complicated when you use the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: private void lblCustomize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if(tabControl1.IsVisible){
        tabControl1.Hide();
    }
    else{
        tabControl1.Show();
    }
}

Comment: i have explained this to the best of my ability. I stated what i did not want, but you still insist of using the things i dont want. If that is the case then i will keep using my app that is done. In the app i used the toolStrip. it looks fine on a bordered form. I am making the app borderless, so i do not want to use the toolStrip. I can not make this any plainer. I have put pictures up and stated i did not want a toolStrip. All i want to know is, is it possible to make a Label into a menu style. Either you don't know or It can not be done. Read the question again carefully!

Comment: OK, you "click" on the label to show or hide the TabControl.  You didn't answer my question though.  You are showing these "floating labels" when you hover your mouse over the label.  What makes these labels disappear?  Do you interact with the "menu labels" in any way?

Comment: When i hover my mouse over the label. i want the label to show the names of the tabs in the tabControl. Like the second picture. I dont want to click anything. I just want it to show the names of each tab. When i click Customize the tabControl will appear. Then i can click the tab and put my info in. Then i click Customize again and the tabControl Hides. I just want to have a list like a menu, give the names of each tab. nothing more, nothing less. Is this possible? Yes or No

Comment: I'm not talking about the TabControl.  What makes the "floating labels" disappear?

Comment: The labels do not disappear. The labels are there to stay put. I have already coded what they do. I just want the Label to have a cascading menu style, to show what tabs are in the tab control.

Comment: would i do something like this     tab1.Items.Add("Commands")  in the mouse hover event

Comment: If they never disappear then why are we using a MouseHover event to show them?  Anyway, just loop: `foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl1.TabPages)`, then just create the label: `Label l = new Label(); l.Text = tp.Text;`  Set the location, etc.

Comment: that is the whole reason of the question. I don't know what to use. Let me explain. In the first app i created 4 years ago. I used the MenuStrip. Did all the programming for the buttons. Since i am now redesigning the UI, I do not want to use the menu strip. If you look at the picture of the UI, where it says Name, it pulls from the textbox that you put your name in. The label changes to the Name in the textbox input. The time changes to time and Date to the date. It would not make since to have a menustrip for one button. Thats why i want to use a label only. Only one label has a click event

Comment: You seem to have ignored the relevant part of my last comment regarding looping through the TabPages.

Comment: You seem to have ignored my question in a whole. Can a label be used as a menu to show the Names of each Tab? In other words can a Label have sub labels? You keep telling to use a ToolStrip, and i keep telling However, I don't want to use a toolStrip. If i did then i would not be redesigning the whole App. So all of your comments have done nothing but wasted time. If you would have read the question and looked at the pictures of what i am trying to do, then you would understand. All you have done is wasted time, and asking non sense questions that are mentioned in the Main Question.

Comment: So I am just going to keep it the way i have it. and not even worry about  sub labels. Since apparently the mile long question with pictures that an elementary school student could understand. You however can not understand the pictures with the words on it what i am trying to do. So I am just going to program it the way i originally intended.

Comment: About 50 people have looked at this question and ignored it while I'm the poor sap trying to help you, and then you call me dense?  Your "image" implies sub-menus below the label you are clicking.  If you tried to do this with "one" label, you would probably end up cutting off the neighboring labels because your "social commands" looks to be too far to the right.

Comment: The picture of the sub labels, is to show i am trying to make sub labels. If i use a Label List view. The label Customize will be listing the tab names. In the picture, the sub labels are indented. to show in the picture they are sub labels. Seriously, You are that dense, that you could not figure that out. My 9 year old daughter new exactly what it was. and she knows nothing about programming. That is just common sense. I am sorry i even tried to explain a question to you. That my 9 year old daughter knew what i was doing by the pictures. If your that dense, then you are a poor sap.

Answer (score 0):

It was painful trying to figure out what you were asking help for, but as near as I can tell, this is probably what you were looking to do:

```
Size originalSize;
String originalText;

void CustomizeLabel_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  originalSize = CustomizeLabel.Size;
  originalText = CustomizeLabel.Text;

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.AppendLine(originalText);
  foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl1.TabPages) {
    sb.AppendLine("    " + tp.Text);
  }

  CustomizeLabel.Text = sb.ToString();
  CustomizeLabel.Height = TextRenderer.MeasureText(CustomizeLabel.Text,
                                                   CustomizeLabel.Font).Height;
}

void CustomizeLabel_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  CustomizeLabel.Text = originalText;
  CustomizeLabel.Size = originalSize;
}
```

Comment: That's what I have been trying to do. I was thinking mouse hover event.. If you would said use mouse enter and mouse leave events.. All that nonsense could of been avoided. Now thank you.